# how to make android activity default background

Tags: android

hey i want  a default screen when my android activity is loading...usually it creates a fully black background effect..that may confuse users..
so i try this code

create a file inside res/values/theme.xml
then put this code..

```
<resources>
<style name="Theme.MyAppTheme" parent="android:style/Theme" >
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
<item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/bid_screen_preparing</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

I also added this file in manifest file like

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:allowClearUserData="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/bid_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:logo="@drawable/bid_logo"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyAppTheme" > ........
```

It works only when i press back button and activity back to his previous one..But when i load one activity to another then it asusual shows the black color...dont know why..

Comment: Are u talking about splash?

Comment: No no I dont want a splash screen...i just want a default background image when an activity take time to loading

Comment: hi have you seen the updated answer?

Comment: is yours problem solved with my answer...?

Comment: no still trying but not solved

Comment: i think the problem is actually ur activity is loaded. the black screen is the activity background so u have to set background for those activity. setting windowsbackground will also help u to match the status bar color to ur app color. also when activity take some time to get into the view.

Answer (score 1):

please change these line

```
<resources>
<style name="Theme.MyAppTheme" parent="android:style/Theme" >
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
<item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/bid_screen_preparing</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

and use these lines

```
<resources>
<style name="MyAppTheme" parent="android:style/Theme.light" >
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
<item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/bid_screen_preparing</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

and remove these lines

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:allowClearUserData="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/bid_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:logo="@drawable/bid_logo"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyAppTheme" > ........
```

to

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:allowClearUserData="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/bid_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:logo="@drawable/bid_logo"
        android:theme="@style/MyAppTheme" > ........
```

Comment: Hey there is no error but this code does not solve my issue...as usual black scrren at the time of new activity loading

Comment: please Use android:windowBackground in your theme.

Comment: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'android:windowBackground' with value 
 '@color/translucent_blue').

Comment: please remove that line ..and please tell me with which device you are testing if it is greater than 4.0 please edit  styles.xml in values-v14. it will solve your problem i think

Answer (score 0):

> It works only when i press back button and activity back to his previous one..But when i load one activity to another then it asusual shows the black color...dont know why..

This is how the system works - if you're just jumping from one activity to the next (like by calling startActivity() from onCreate(), the system won't bother drawing anything to prevent a flickering effect (this was explained by Dianne Hackborn a while back on the Android Developer forums).

If you're trying to implement a loading screen, you need to spawn off an AsyncTask that does the loading work off the main thread then starts the next activity when it's finished. Then your first activity will have time to draw the "loading" message.